# Link to download a zip file in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download

I have a zip file in the server. I would like to download that file on click of a link.

Is there a way to create a link to download the zip file in JSF or PrimeFaces, like below HTML5 `download` attribute in client side?

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

Comment: For your knowledge, take a look in `p:fileDownload`, it may help you someday: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml

Comment: @Pellizon: that's only useful if you don't have a concrete file on disk, but only an `InputStream` or `byte[]` in a JSF managed bean.

Answer (score 8):

The HTML5 `download` attribute has got nothing to do with it. It just allows you to specify an alternate filename which should appear in *Save As* dialog.

E.g.

```
<a href="foo.zip" download="bar.zip" />
```

will show the *Save As* dialog with `bar.zip` as filename, but actually provide content of `foo.zip`. Do note that the `bar.zip` doesn't necessarily need to exist in server.

---

As to your concrete problem, there are several ways of serving a file download in a JSF web application.

1. Just put that file in public web content folder.

   ```
   WebContent
    |-- META-INF
    |-- WEB-INF
    |-- files
    |    `-- foo.zip
    |-- page.xhtml
    :
   ```

   Then you can refer it as:

   ```
   <a href="#{request.contextPath}/files/foo.zip">download foo.zip</a>
   ```
2. Or, if it's an external folder and you can't move it into public web content, then just tell the server to publish it. E.g. when you have all those files in `/path/to/files` path and you're using Tomcat server, then add the following into `<Host>` element of Tomcat's `/conf/server.xml`:

   ```
   <Context docBase="/path/to/files" path="/files" />
   ```

   Then you can refer it as:

   ```
   <a href="/files/foo.zip">download foo.zip</a>
   ```
3. Or, if you have no control over server configuration somehow, or can't figure the server-specific way of publishing an arbitrary folder as a new web context, or it represents a temporary storage folder which you'd rather not publish into web, then create a web servlet which does the job. Leaving caching and resume outside consideration, it's as simple as:

   ```
   @WebServlet("/files/*")
   public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {

       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
           File file = new File("/path/to/files", filename);
           response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimetype(filename));
           response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
           response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
           Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
       }

   }
   ```

   You can refer it the same way as #1:

   ```
   <a href="#{request.contextPath}/files/foo.zip">download foo.zip</a>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Though this is an old question, I would like to add this to @BalusC's answer for completeness (coudn't comment due to low reputation): The third solution by @BalusC ( with @WebServlet) can lead to 'Path Traversal Attack', if copy pasted as is.

You may try the attack(for Linux server) using URL:

```
<yourApplicationURLUntilContextPath>/files/%C0%AE/%C0%AE/%C0%AE/%C0%AE/%C0%AE/%C0%AE/%C0%AE/%C0%AE/%C0%AE/%C0%AE/etc/passwd
```

There are various solutions to this problem. One being, add the below check before copying the file to output stream:

```
if(!file.getAbsolutePath().equals(file.getCanonicalPath()))
{
response.sendError(404);
}
```

You may refer the [link](https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/path-traversal-attack-solutions/) for more solutions to path traversal attack.

Hope it helps some developer...